# Setting up virtual environment for python

Tags: python, cygwin, python-venv

Please excuse me if I sound really ignorant, but I am a complete newbie when it comes to tech/IT. In your answers assume I dont know anything because I probably don't. I learned to use terminal yesterday, so only know basic commands. I havent yet gotten fully comfortable with terminal. The command line program I am using is cygwin. Running it on a windows 10 machine. I am working with python3.

I've completed a beginner python course and now wanted to start building real world projects. I am trying to set up a virtual environment so I can start building a python project. IThese are the following steps I took:

1. I created a project directory called Projects and then inside that created a directory for my actual project called Marketing project.

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Python/Python385/Projects/Marketing Project
```

2. I tried running the python3 -m venv env command to create a virtual environment called env and it did not work. I got the following error:

```
$ python3 -m venv env

- bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/44784/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3: Permission denied
```

How do I fix this problem so that this command can work?

Comment: Hello Ange, Nice to see you on Stack Overflow! I'm glad you're getting better at python. It's a great language. A couple of things : 
1. You're not actually running python3 because of file perms. You may need to run a chmod 755 on the target file.
2. Just as a larger note...not sure why you need a virtual environment to run python projects. I run Spyder IDE From Anaconda distribution on Windows. Works pretty good. Pycharm is also pretty good. Both are windows compatible. If you're new, I wouldn't be messing with virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Python 3 version, virtual environment support is included in it, so all you need to do to create one is this:

```py
$ python3 -m venv venv
```

Here, I am asking Python to run the package `venv` and create a virtual environment named `venv`. The first `venv` in the command is the name of the Python virtual environment package, and the second is the virtual environment name that you can use for the particular environment. Feel free to replace the second `venv` with a different name that you want to assign to your virtual environment.

After the command completes, you are going to have a directory named 'venv' where the virtual environment files are stored.

If you are using any version of Python older than 3.4 (including the 2.7 release), virtual environments are not supported natively. For those versions of Python, you need to download and install a third-party tool called [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) before you can create virtual environments.

Once `virtualenv` is installed, you can create a virtual environment with the following command:

```py
$ virtualenv venv
```

Regardless of the method you used to create it, you should have your virtual environment created. To activate your brand new virtual environment you use the following command:

```py
$ source venv/bin/activate

# Output
(venv)$
```

If you are using a Microsoft Windows command prompt window, the activation command is slightly different:

```py
$ venv\Scripts\activate
```

With your virtual environment created and activated, you can finally install all your project packages.

## Another method of creating and activating virtual environment

### Virtualenvwrapper

I would also like to introduce you to the concept of `virtualenvwrapper`. The [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper/) is a set of extensions that allow for creating and deleting virtual environments and, basically, managing your development workflow, making it easier to work on more than one project at a time without introducing conflicts in their dependencies.

I will show you how to set up your python environment to use virtualenvironment wrapper in Ubuntu 20.04. What you will need to do is:

1. Install `pip3` (if you haven't already)
2. Install `virtualenv`
3. Install `virtualenvwrapper`
4. Edit `.bashrc/` file or `.bash_profile` file, or both

#### Setting Up a Virtual Environment

Open your terminal in your home directory (or any other directory you may choose). First, you need to create a special directory which will be hidden that will store all your virtual environments

Create a hidden virtual environments folder:

```py
$ mkdir .virtualenv # the dot(.) denotes that the file is hidden
```

Install `pip3`:

```py
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Confirm installation of `pip3`:

```py
$ pip3 --version # checks for the version of pip3
$ which pip3 # shows you the location of pip3 in your system
```

Install `virtualenv` using `pip3`:

```py
$ pip3 install virtualenv # install virtualenv
$ which virtualenv # find where it is located
```

Now, it is time to install `virtualenvwrapper`:

```py
$ pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

You will modify your `.bashrc` file by adding a row that will adjust every new virtual environment to use `Python3`. You will need to point virtual environments to the directory you created above ( the '.virtualenv')

Open the `.bashrc` file using your `vim` editor:

```py
$ vim .bashrc
```

If you notice that you do not have `vim` in your system, make sure you install it through:

```py
$ sudo apt install vim
```

`.bashrc` file will open in your terminal. Something you should note about the vim editor is that it does not use the conventional editing commands such as `ctrl + C` etc. Rather, it uses its own special commands to allow you interact with it. Learn how to navigate the vim editor [here](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/vim-101-beginners-guide-vim/).

For now, there are two basic commands you need to know:

- How to enter into `insert` mode so you can make edits
- How to `save and quit`

Now that your editor is open, you need to start making changes. Scroll to the bottom of the file by pressing the down arrow key. At the very bottom of your editor, press the letter `i` on your keyboard to enter into insert mode (`i` could mean 'insert').

Add these rows:

```py
#Virtualenvwrapper settings:
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
. /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Press `esc` and type `:wq` then press `Enter`. This will allow you to save your changes and quit the editor. Close your terminal and reopen it.

Now you need to reload the `bashrc` script. There are two ways to do it:

1. Close and reopen the terminal (done above) or
2. Execute this command in the terminal: `source ~/.bashrc`

You have completed setting up your virtual environment.

#### Create Your Virtual Environment

With the setup now complete, you can use `virtualenvwrapper`.

`virtualenvwrapper` allows you to create and activate your virtual environment at the same time. To create your virtual environment, use the command `mkvirtualenv`:

```py
$  mkvirtualenv <name-of-your-virtual-environment> # for example mkvirtualenv marketing_app

# Output
(marketing_app)$
```

To deactivate your virtual environment, run:

```py
(marketing_app)$ deactivate

# Output
$
```

`virtualenvwrapper` has several commands that allow you to manage your virtual environment very easily. Example commands include:

- `mkvirtualenv` (create and activate - at the same time - a new virtual environment)
- `workon` (used to activate an existing virtual environment)
- `rmvirtualenv` (delete an existing virtual environment)
- `cpvirtualenv` (copy an existing virtual environment)

#### Summary of virtualenvwrapper

As soon as you have completed your initial setup, all you will need to do moving forward will be to use the commands above.

To create a new virtual environment you will need to simply run this command:

```py
$ mkvirtualenv marketing_app # create and activate virtual environment
```

Comment: As you introduced the process of how to set up a virtualenvwrapper I'm actually confused about what the actual advantage in comparison to the natively supported `python3 -m venv venv_name` is?